# Keyframe rules not working on firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Animations not working on firefox but working on chrome and IE. please help Keyframe rules are set for moz  @-moz-keyframes cf4FadeInOut the problem is that all keyframes rules are set for webkit moz and -o- but still not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/eVULR/1/

```
/* full image slider */
    @-webkit-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
       0% {opacity:1;}
       19% {opacity:1;}
       25% {opacity:0;}
       94% {opacity:0;}
       100% {opacity:1;}
    }

    @-moz-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
       0% {opacity:1;}
       19% {opacity:1;}
       25% {opacity:0;}
       94% {opacity:0;}
       100% {opacity:1;}
    }

    @-o-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
       0% {opacity:1;}
       19% {opacity:1;}
       25% {opacity:0;}
       94% {opacity:0;}
       100% {opacity:1;}
    }

    @keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
       0% {opacity:1;}
       19% {opacity:1;}
       25% {opacity:0;}
       94% {opacity:0;}
       100% {opacity:1;}
    }
    #cf4a
    {
    overflow:hidden;
    position: fixed; 
    top: -50%; 
    left: -50%; 
    width:  200%; 
    height: 200%;
    background-color:black;
    }

    #cf4a img
    {
     position: absolute; 
      top: 0; 
      left: 0; 
      right: 0; 
      bottom: 0; 
      margin: auto; 
      min-width: 50%;
      min-height: 50%;
    }
    #cf4a img {
       -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;

       -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -moz-animation-duration: 20s;

       -o-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -o-animation-duration: 20s;

       animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       animation-duration: 20s;
    }



    #page-wrap, #cf4a img:nth-of-type(1) {
       -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
       -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
       -o-animation-delay: 0s;
       animation-delay: 0s;

        z-index:4;
    }
    #page-wrap{
     -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;

       -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -moz-animation-duration: 20s;

       -o-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -o-animation-duration: 20s;

       animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       animation-duration: 20s;
     -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
       -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
       -o-animation-delay: 3s;
       animation-delay: 3s;

        z-index:5;
    }

    #page-wrap1,#cf4a img:nth-of-type(2) {
       -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
       -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
       -o-animation-delay: 4s;
       animation-delay: 4s;

        z-index:3;
    }
    #page-wrap1{
     -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;

       -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -moz-animation-duration: 20s;

       -o-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -o-animation-duration: 20s;

       animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       animation-duration: 20s;
     -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
       -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
       -o-animation-delay: 0s;
       animation-delay: 0s;

        z-index:3;
    }



    #page-wrap2,#cf4a img:nth-of-type(3) {
       -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
       -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
       -o-animation-delay: 8s;
       animation-delay: 8s;

        z-index:2;
    }
    #page-wrap2{
     -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;

       -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -moz-animation-duration: 20s;

       -o-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -o-animation-duration: 20s;

       animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
       animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       animation-duration: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
       -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
       -o-animation-delay: 4s;
       animation-delay: 4s;

        z-index:2;
    }


    #page-wrap,#cf4a img:nth-of-type(4) {
       -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
       -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
       -o-animation-delay: 12s;
       animation-delay: 12s;

        z-index:1;
    }
```

Comment: This would be easier to diagnose with a link as one could run it through fire bug

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eVULR/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you would like a pure CSS solution, but that is not possible right now. Many of the browsers still have not gotten up to the new CSS capabilities.

I would suggest jQuery for your solution. There are several functions within the API such as slideIn(), fadeIn(), fadeOut(), .toggle() etc...

Using these functions is as simple as waiting for DOM ready and then applying your class for the effect your looking for. A quick example is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".myButton").hover(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
    });
});//end dom
</script>
```

Comment: Sadly as much as I love CSS it has so many limitations when using web-kits. jQuery reduces those browser quarks, it might be a bit slower buy for compatibility I have to say jQuery is the best.